# Accessing elements inside a datatemplate in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

Hi I would like to access the controls inside a datatemplate in the ResourceDictinory.xaml file from the code behind.

my ResFile1.xaml content

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataTemplate x:Key="btnTemplate1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="Abcd123" Foreground="Red"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox" Text="textbox Text"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

ok.I am using it like this in MainPage.xaml

```
        <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResFile1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="152" Margin="106,221,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="256" 
        ContentTemplate="{Binding ConverterParameter=blabla, Converter={StaticResource TestResConverter}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource btnTemplate1}}"/>
    </Grid>
```

My TestResConverter class.(accessing elements inside datatemplate in this class)

```
    public class ConverterTest : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DataTemplate)
        {
            DataTemplate dataTemplate = value as DataTemplate;
            //access elements
            TextBox accessedTextbox = XXXMehod(dataTemplate);
            accessedTextbox.Text = (string)parameter;//e.g change text property
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

How to access elements inside datatemplate?What is accessing, editing alternative to DataTemplate?Also i look at the wpf projects but some methods not exist wp7.

Answer (score 0):

use `ItemContainerGenerator`.
here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

Comment: Not exist FindName method for DataTemplate in wp7.Also what is relevance with ItemContainerGenerator?i am not using ListBoxItem.